# Accessing column of groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table which looks like this:

```
 Bank        Our Credit Rating      External Credit Rating       Deviation
 A             11                      12                          1
 D             10                      8                           2
 A             4                       4                           0
 B             6                       7                           1
 C             12                      11                          1
 A             9                       10                          1
```

The banks for which the sum of all deviations combined is >=50 are to be extracted. I have done the same via the code given above.

Output:

```
   [IN]
   workbbok = pd.read_csv("Credit_Rating_comparison.csv")
   df33= workbook.groupby('Bank').aggregate({"Deviation":np.sum})
   df44=df33[df33['Deviation']>=50]
   [OUT]
    Bank                                      Deviation                                  
    B                                          68.0
    A                                          72.0

    and so on for the relevant banks. (Basically sum of all deviations for 
    one bank where sum of all deviations is at least 50)
```

I am **unable to access column 1** that is **name of all the banks in df44**.

```
    [IN]: df44.columns
    [OUT]: Index(['Deviation'], dtype='object')
    [IN]: df44.iloc[:,0]
    [OUT]
     Bank                                      
     B                                          68.0
     A                                          72.0
     #Using df44.iloc[:,0] doesnt give column name deviation also and 
     returns deviation results along with Bank name.  I want only bank names list.
```

Basically I need a list of only the bank names (without the sum of deviation) so that I can further use that list for below operations.

After I get the names of all the banks I need to find the frequency distribution of the Deviation column.

Below code gives frequency bin corresponding to all the rows. I want to **extract only the rows where bank name is in df44['Bank']**. Any help will be appreciated.

```
     [IN]:
     bins = [0, 1,2,3,4,5]
     workbook['Deviation Bins'] = pd.cut(workbook['Deviation'], bins, 
     include_lowest =True)
     workbook 
     [OUT]:
 Bank   Our Credit Rating  External Credit Rating Deviation  Deviation Bins
 A             11                      12              1        (-inf.,1]
 D             10                      8               2        (1,2]
 A             4                       4               0        (-inf.,1]
 B             6                       7               1        (-inf.,1]
 C             12                      11              1        (-inf.,1]  
 A             9                       10              1        (-inf.,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `.aggregate()`, the groups go into the index of the returned data frame rather than a column. What you can do is turn the index into a new column, e.g.:

```
df33['Bank'] = df33.index
```

Then you can filter out the groups of interest:

```
df44=df33[df33['Deviation']>=50]
```

For the second part, you need to use `.isin()`:

```
workbook[workbook['Bank'].isin(df44['Bank'])]
```

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Sorry, it was a typo when I was adapting my script. It should read df33. I've just edited the answer. Please let me know if there are any other issues with the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help ex-pndit. The code worked fine :)

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor That's great to hear, glad to be of help!